# Notation for limit points of a minimizing sequence: $\arg \inf$

Tags: analysis, notation, optimization

Could you tell me what is the accepted notation for the set of limit points of a minimizing sequence. For example, if I have a function $f(x)$ and a sequence $x_t$ such that

$\lim f(x_t) = \inf f(x)$

I want a notation for the (possibly empty) set of limit points of all such sequences. I thought of using

$\arg \inf$

but it is a bit misleading because no *argument* may actually achieve the $\inf$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've never seen a standard notation for this.  $\arg\inf$ looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the reply

Comment: Is arginf even possible? If the infimum is a point in the space, it is a minimum. If there is no min, but only a limiting inf, then there is no arginf.