# What does "arg inf" mean?

Tags: analysis, notation

I noticed this term on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89360/notation-for-limit-points-of-a-minimizing-sequence-arg-inf).

But the term **arg inf** is not clearly defined.

Comment: I think "arg inf" is found in certain computer programming languages.  In mathematics, it is usually not written that way.

Answer (score 7):

It refers to the argument of the function such that the function attains its infimum (or minimum). For example, let $f(x) = x^2-x$. Then $\arg\inf f(x) = {1\over 2}$ because $f(x)$ attains its minimum at $x= {1\over 2}$.

Comment: If one bothers to say inf instead of min, then the function does not *attain* it, so the notation is indeed meaningless.